# Kafka Streams API - Aggregation Persistence using custom timestamps

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using the Kafka Streams API and I'm not sure if the behavior I am seeing is a bug or something I'm not understanding correctly.

### Context

I'll start by saying I'm new to stream processing. I have some data that is currently batch processed and would like to feed it into a streaming system. The caveat is that I cannot add events directly to the stream cluster right now - they have to pass through an intermediate system that stores the records and loads them into a database (here, I will add a Kafka producer).

Furthermore, the intermediate system is a cluster of machines that a load balancer will round-robin. This means that records can be received late if one of the machines ends up having an issue. Due to the delays and ordering issues, I'd like to use event-time semantics by specifying my own custom timestamp extractor. Every record has an embedded timestamp.

I'm using Kafka 0.11.01.

### The Problem

I found the Streams DSL to be very attractive based on the ease of implementing windowed aggregation functions and the built-in state stores. When running the application, everything works fine. **However, when restarting the application, the state of the aggregations seem to be lost** - if counting, for example, the count will start at 0 instead of the last value. I think it has something to do with using both a custom timestamp and windowed aggregation functions because it works as expected when using a built-in timestamp.

### Example Application (Java 8)

It's kind of hard to have a push-button example, so this one requires a bit of work. A dev kafka server with kafka console commands is required to run it. This application just counts records... the value of each record is the timestamp. The behavior I mentioned can be re-produced with the following:

1. Start a producer and publish a the following message: "Test:1"

   > kafka-console-producer --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:" --topic test-topic`
2. Start a consumer (note: it consumes the output topic, which counts records).

   > kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --from-beginning --property print.key=true --property key.separator=":" --value-deserializer org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer --topic test-output
3. Run the application (I prefer to do a installDist with Gradle and run from the build directory).
4. Send a few more messages (the value needs to be in the same window). "Test:2","Test:3". The output should have 3 counted. You can send a "Test:501" if you want, and it will display 1, as it is in another window.
5. Kill the application (ctrl+c the command window).
6. Restart application.
7. Send "Test:4". It will output a 1, indicating there is only one record in that time window, even though there should be 4.

Here is what I see when running it:

> Producer->Test:1
>   Consumer->Test:1
>   Producer->Test:2
>   Producer->Test:3
>   Consumer->Test:3
>   Restart
>   Producer->Test:4
>   Consumer->Test:1

I would expect the last consumer record to be Test:4, as there are 4 records in the window 0-500.

When using the built-in timestamp, Kafka will continue aggregating where it left off if the application restarts. Also, if I use a custom timestamp without windows, it will also work fine.

#### Main.class

```java
package test.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindows;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-consumer-client");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG,"test.kafka.CustomKafkaTimestamp");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG,"var/");

        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

        KStream<String,String> testStream = builder.stream("test-topic");
        testStream.foreach((key,value)->logger.info("Got "+key+"="+value));
        testStream.groupByKey().count(TimeWindows.of(500))
                .toStream()
                .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key.key(),value))
                .to(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Long(),"test-output");

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder,streamsConfiguration);
        streams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(()->{streams.close(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); streams.cleanUp();}));
    }
}
```

#### CustomKafkaTimestamp.class

```java
package test.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor;

public class CustomKafkaTimestamp implements TimestampExtractor {
    @Override
    public long extract(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> record, long previousTimestamp) {
        if (record.value() instanceof String) {
            String str = (String) record.value();
            return Long.parseLong(str);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### build.gradle

```java
group 'local.kafka'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'test.kafka.Main'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.11.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:0.11.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.10.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

**Edit/Update**

As suggested, I tried running the code with version 1.0.0. It still did not work, but this time it stack traced and crashed. At this point it is also worth noting I'm on a Windows system for development - it looks like it is trying to create a colon in a directory name.

I tried running the client on a Linux vm. With 0.11.01, it behaves the same as my original description. Using 1.0 on Linux results in expected behavior - state is preserved between restarts.

The stacktrace on Windows using Streams 1.0.0:

```
10:50:48.188 [] INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [kafka-consumer-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
10:50:48.189 [] INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [kafka-consumer-client]State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
10:50:48.225 [] INFO  test.kafka.Main - Got Test=1
10:50:48.230 [] INFO  test.kafka.Main - Got Test=2
10:51:19.753 [] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager - task [0_0] Failed to flush state store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:0 at location var\test\0_0\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:0
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:204) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:174) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segment.openDB(Segment.java:40) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segments.getOrCreateSegment(Segments.java:89) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.put(RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.java:81) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore$RocksDBWindowBytesStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:43) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore$RocksDBWindowBytesStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:34) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:67) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:33) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore$1.apply(CachingWindowStore.java:100) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:141) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:99) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:127) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.flush(CachingWindowStore.java:132) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.flush(MeteredWindowStore.java:128) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:245) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState(AbstractTask.java:196) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:324) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask$1.run(StreamTask.java:304) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:299) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:289) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks$2.apply(AssignedTasks.java:87) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.applyToRunningTasks(AssignedTasks.java:451) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit(AssignedTasks.java:380) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll(TaskManager.java:309) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:1018) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:835) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Failed to create dir: C:\Users\Chris Lastname\IdeaProjects\kafka-test\build\install\kafka-test\bin\var\test\0_0\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:0: Invalid argument
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method) ~[rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:?]
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(RocksDB.java:231) ~[rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:197) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        ... 29 more
10:51:19.757 [] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks - stream-thread [kafka-consumer-client-StreamThread-1] Failed to commit stream task 0_0 due to the following error:
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: task [0_0] Failed to flush state store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:248) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState(AbstractTask.java:196) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:324) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask$1.run(StreamTask.java:304) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:299) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:289) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks$2.apply(AssignedTasks.java:87) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.applyToRunningTasks(AssignedTasks.java:451) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit(AssignedTasks.java:380) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll(TaskManager.java:309) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:1018) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:835) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744) [kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:0 at location var\test\0_0\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:0
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:204) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:174) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segment.openDB(Segment.java:40) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segments.getOrCreateSegment(Segments.java:89) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.put(RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.java:81) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore$RocksDBWindowBytesStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:43) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore$RocksDBWindowBytesStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:34) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:67) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:33) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore$1.apply(CachingWindowStore.java:100) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:141) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:99) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:127) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.flush(CachingWindowStore.java:132) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.flush(MeteredWindowStore.java:128) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:245) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Failed to create dir: C:\Users\Chris Lastname\IdeaProjects\kafka-test\build\install\kafka-test\bin\var\test\0_0\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:0: Invalid argument
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method) ~[rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:?]
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(RocksDB.java:231) ~[rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:197) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:174) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segment.openDB(Segment.java:40) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segments.getOrCreateSegment(Segments.java:89) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.put(RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.java:81) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore$RocksDBWindowBytesStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:43) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore$RocksDBWindowBytesStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:34) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:67) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:33) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore$1.apply(CachingWindowStore.java:100) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:141) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:99) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:127) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.flush(CachingWindowStore.java:132) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.flush(MeteredWindowStore.java:128) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:245) ~[kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:?]
        ... 14 more
10:51:19.760 [] INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [kafka-consumer-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
10:51:19.761 [] INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [kafka-consumer-client-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
10:51:19.765 [] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=kafka-consumer-client-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
10:51:19.770 [] INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [kafka-consumer-client-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
10:51:19.772 [] INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [kafka-consumer-client]State transition from RUNNING to ERROR
10:51:19.772 [] WARN  org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [kafka-consumer-client]All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
```

Comment: This is a dumb question (hence why I'm leaving it in a comment :)), but have you tried starting your consumer without `--from-beginning`?

Comment: No worries :) I tried it just to be sure and it did not change anything. I'm pretty sure the issue lies in the Streams API setup in Main.class.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Hard to say atm what might be the issue. I am wondering why you call `stream.cleanup()` though? But this should not affect correctness of the behavior. Maybe you want to try out 1.0.0, version? You can register a restore callback to monitor is state is recreated correctly on startup.

Comment: The call to cleanup() is just because I'm still in early development.. my understanding was it is necessary to use that to clean the local cache between runs, if you want a clean slate (in addition to server-side cleanup). I tried using 1.0.0 and updated the original question accordingly.

Comment: The issue on MS Windows is sometimes RocksDB... Can you try to replace RocksDB with in-memory store on Windows for both versions to see it this fixes the issue for you? The "colon" is a know issues and is fixed already in `trunk`: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6167